# What should be our site's tagline?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

As Mithrandir suggested [in this post](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/207), we can promote our site on other community sites like [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) via a Community Promotion Ads.

But our potential ad may need a tagline, like our site when it will graduate.

That's here the community needs you! **What should be our site's tagline?**

I suggest to post one idea per answer to facilitate community voting.

Comment: "Save a cow: eat a vegetarian"?

Comment: Or another tongue-in-cheek favourite, "Save a cow; eat a beaver"?  Oh wait...

Answer (score 0):

Let me just take a first shot.

> Live. Let live. Enjoy.

I think this conveys in a tongue-in-cheek kind of way that this site is about veg*anism, it's targeted to the gourmets over at 'seasoned advice', and the allusion to laissez-faire hopefully helps against the stereotype of preachy do-gooders on a moral high ground.

Comment: I do not think veg*anism should be specifically about letting live. It's a life choice that can be powered by many reasons, including the one you mentionned. When I read your line I feel the contempt you have against people not sticking to your lifestyle and it does not makes me want to join your community.

Comment: @Winter Oh, that's really the opposite of what I want to convey, but it doesn't seem to come across. Live and let live also means let everyone live according to their own values. No contempt whatsoever.

Comment: Maybe "Live and let live. Enjoy."?

Comment: I like the idea here, but I do agree that it unintentionally comes across as preachy, which is the opposite of the author's stated intent.

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple, like:

> Enjoying plant-based eating